# Calculate a square root using the Newton method in Python

Tags: python, square, square-root

I have a task to calculate a square root using the Newton method using a function within a function. The user enters a number that he wants to know his root and another number that is his guess to the root.
The program I made works but the problem is that it only works for integer numbers.
Although I convert the input to float when I set for example the number 2 and for example a guess 1 it gives me only the integer and not the decimal i mean instead of 1.4142 it gives 1.
I would love to understand where the problem is. Thanks in advance !

my code :

```
def mySqrt2():
  
    number=float(input('enter a number that you want to find its root:'))
    n=float(input('enter your Guess:'))
    
    def mySqrt1(number,n):
        
        def checkIfGood():
            def ImprovingGuess():
                newguess=n
                i=0
                while i!=100:
                    temp=number//newguess
                    newguess=(temp+newguess)//2.0
                    i+=1
       
                return newguess
            
            if n == (number**.5):
                return 'your guess is good!'
            else:
                return ImprovingGuess()
            
        return checkIfGood()        
    return mySqrt1(number,n)

print('The result is :',mySqrt2())
```

Comment: Why are you using integer division (`//` rather than `/`) if you want to work with floats?

Comment: And Newton's method converges really fast, doubling the number of decimal places each time.  ImprovingGuess really only needs to do one iteration.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, @JohnColeman identified the problem.  You're using integer division, and you shouldn't be.  And Frank is also right; you will never need more than 3 or 4 iterations.  100 is silly.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need all those nested functions. Just put the code for them where you're currently calling them (with appropriately renamed variables). There's seldom a good reason to define a (non-recursive) function and then immediately call it once. If you are doing that, the function is not needed!